# Pass Initial Value to Cubit

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

[image]

I have multiple filter in view. I added Cubit Bloc pattern for state management. When user tap on box, its colors will be changed. I achieved this using cubit. But I have multiple filter with the same UI. The question is I want to use same Cubit by passing different filter paramter in initialization. I have below **parameter_cubit.dart** file

```
 class ParameterCubit extends Cubit<ParameterState> {
  ParameterCubit()
      : super(ParameterState(
            isAllCheck: false, arrParameter: AppGlobals.arrShape));
            
  void onParameterClick(int id) {
    int cntAllCheck = 0;
    List<TblSearchParameter> arrParam = state.arrParameter;
    int indexParameter =
        arrParam.indexWhere((parameter) => (parameter.id == id));

    if (indexParameter != null) {
      TblSearchParameter objSearchParameter = arrParam[indexParameter];
      objSearchParameter.isCheck = objSearchParameter.isCheck != null
          ? !objSearchParameter.isCheck
          : true;
      arrParam[indexParameter] = objSearchParameter;

      for (TblSearchParameter obj in arrParam) {
        if (obj.isCheck) {
          cntAllCheck++;
        }
      }

      emit(ParameterState(
          isAllCheck: cntAllCheck == arrParam.length ? true : false,
          arrParameter: arrParam));
    }
  }
}
```

I want to pass dynamic array based on filter in **arrParameter:** in below line of above class.

```
ParameterCubit()
      : super(ParameterState(
            isAllCheck: false, arrParameter: AppGlobals.arrShape));
```

So how to do that? So I can use same cubit class for different filter by passing array. There is not any API call in this page, all the data are static.